# at android.view.layoutinflater.createviewfromtag(layoutinflater.java:738)

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-recyclerview

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange(RecyclerView.java:1216)
at android.view.View.onDrawScrollBars(View.java:12943)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15237)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.draw(RecyclerView.java:2440)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15140)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15140)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.drawChild(DrawerLayout.java:1086)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15138)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15140)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:53)
at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3405)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3198)
at android.view.View.draw(View.java:15234)
```

I created a hello world app. When I closed my Android Studio and opened it, I get this error. Any solution?

Comment: i resolverd my problem whit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259335/npe-while-inflating-layout-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-boolean-java-lang

Comment: Change <view to <View, because view is not about empty view. It's for custom view defined through class attr, like below:

<view
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    class="com.your.package.YourCustomView" />