# Getting Binary XML file line #141: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

Logcat

```
05-11 19:14:52.567 4489-4489/? E/AndroidRuntime: 
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                  
       Process: com.grab.deals.dealcart, PID: 4489
       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.grab.deals.dealcart/com.grab.deals.dealcart.Full_view.Full_view}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #141: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
       Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #141: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
       at com.grab.deals.dealcart.Full_view.Full_view.onCreate(Full_view.java:13)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616) 
       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:738)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:835)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:838)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:798)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
       at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
       at com.grab.deals.dealcart.Full_view.Full_view.onCreate(Full_view.java:13) 
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6237) 
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

ExtendView.xml

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_full_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="5dp">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"

            android:id="@+id/img"/>
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Designer shirt"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000"/>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="12dp"
                    android:text="Speatial Price"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:textColor="#34a853"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:text="Ends in few hours"
                   />
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="25,000"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="#000"/>
                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:text="70%off"
                    android:textSize="15dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="#34a853"
                android:text="4.1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_24dp"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp">


 <ImageView
     android:layout_width="30dp"
     android:layout_height="30dp"
     app:srcCompat="@drawable/copy"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Copy Coupon"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        />


</LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


        <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            >
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:text="Details"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#000"/>
                <view
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1dp"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:textSize="17sp"
                    android:textColor="#000"
                    android:layout_margin="20dp"
                    android:text="Heighlets \n*shgdfshdflshflsjh\n*a;sjkdfjshgf"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Terms and Conditions"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#000"/>
                    <view
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"/>

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="17sp"
                        android:textColor="#000"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:text="Heighlets \n*shgdfshdflshflsjh\n*a;sjkdfjshgf"/>
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="5dp"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:text="Ratings &amp; Reviews"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:textColor="#000"/>
                    <view
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="1dp"/>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:layout_margin="20dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="4.1"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:textSize="40sp"/>
                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="50dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_star_border_black_24dp"/>
                    </LinearLayout>
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:text="1,500 Reviews"
                            />
                    </LinearLayout>

                           </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center">
    <Button
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Share"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Visit"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>



</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Full_View.java

```
public class Full_View extends Fragment {

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootview = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_full_view,container,false);
        return rootview;
    }

}
```

Comment: Post the onCreate() method of Full_view.java

Comment: Done @billynomates

Comment: it is already mention itself in logcat line# 141

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPE while inflating layout (Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34259335/npe-while-inflating-layout-attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-boolean-java-lang)

Answer (score 397, accepted):

```
 <view
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"/>
```

Change `view` to `View` 
 *(lowercase `v` to uppercase `V`)*

Comment: This is so annoying. Why Android Studio warn about this?

Comment: also make sure to use `View (upper v)` instead of `view (lower v)` as mention by @Sudhir singh

Answer (score 13):

please

```
         <view
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>
```

Change  to

```
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

It is view in your ExtendView.xml ,View replace it.

Answer (score -1):

Your are writing view wrong, it should be View

Comment: How does this add anything to the existing accepted answer?

Comment: I was stuck in this issue for 3 hours,
Just wanted to make sure for anyone who check this post this is the right answer

Comment: It‘s better to express this by up voting the correct answer instead of adding another one with essentially the same content.